# The specified command i is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`

Tags: angular

I am trying to install **infinite scroll module** but given command not working.

```
command : npm i ngx-infinite-scroll
```

> Error :- The specified command i is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, worked for me : `npm -i install ngx-infinite-scroll`

`i` is just short for `install`.

`npm i ngx-infinite-scroll` = `npm install ngx-infinite-scroll`

But `npm -i install ngx-infinite-scroll` this also works.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npm install ngx-infinite-scroll
```

Also you can find all available commands in [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm)

Comment: working Thanks But I want to know how make it difference with above one.

Comment: as the error says there is no "i" command, you have to use "install" command to install

Answer (score 0):

My answer isn't specifically for infinite scroll module but its general, I cloned the app and was trying to run it with command `ionic serve` without even installing modules first by `npm install` and was facing such issue.